# Get customers name in confirmation email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working with Woocommerce and I am about to make the order confirmation email.

It want the mail to say:

> "Hi [customers name]"

How do you get Woocommerce to print the customers name?

Comment: You have to show research efforts when posting a Question: [ask]. . . Drop the plugin folder in your favorite Code Editor and do a global search for "confirmation email", then post your findings here. Maybe just a function name may lead to an existent solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need the order object, so depending on what hook you are using it should be there. Try something like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed','my_woo_email');
function my_woo_email($order_id){

           $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
           $to = $order->billing_email;
           $subject = 'this is my subject';
           $message = 'Hi '.$order->billing_first_name.' '.$order->billing_email;$order->billing_last_name.', thanks for the order!';

                woocommerce_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers = "Content-Type: text/htmlrn", $attachments = "" )

}
```

This is untested but should get you started

Comment: how about if I want to display username of customer?

Comment: Got its solutions. $order has a key 'customer_user' that holds user id.

Answer (score 11):

As of WooCommerce 3.x the `$order` object's properties should not be accessed directly as suggested in the previous answers. The proper way is now:

```
echo 'Hi ' . $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_last_name();
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's my starter example of getting a bunch of the WooCommerce customer info inside a `WP_Query` loop:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status'    => 'any',
    'post_type'      => 'shop_order',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'          => 'ASC'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    $query->the_post();

    $order    = new WC_Order( $query->post->ID );

    echo $order->billing_address_1;
    echo $order->billing_address_2;
    echo $order->billing_city;
    echo $order->billing_company;
    echo $order->billing_country;
    echo $order->billing_email;
    echo $order->billing_first_name;
    echo $order->billing_last_name;
    echo $order->billing_phone;
    echo $order->billing_postcode;
    echo $order->billing_state;
    echo $order->cart_discount;
    echo $order->cart_discount_tax;
    echo $order->customer_ip_address;
    echo $order->customer_user;
    echo $order->customer_user_agent;
    echo $order->order_currency;
    echo $order->order_discount;
    echo $order->order_key;
    echo $order->order_shipping;
    echo $order->order_shipping_tax;
    echo $order->order_tax;
    echo $order->order_total;
    echo $order->payment_method;
    echo $order->payment_method_title;
    echo $order->shipping_address_1;
    echo $order->shipping_address_2;
    echo $order->shipping_city;
    echo $order->shipping_company;
    echo $order->shipping_country;
    echo $order->shipping_first_name;
    echo $order->shipping_last_name;
    echo $order->shipping_method_title;
    echo $order->shipping_postcode;
    echo $order->shipping_state;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Hopefully this will be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

you can get customer data from `$order` object, something like this.

```
$customer = get_userdata( $order->get_customer_id() );
$name = $customer->display_name;
```