# Display customers name in email using woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I am working on an email campaign and I am trying to display the users name in an email after the customer has made an order online and has entered their information via the form.

When I test (not using a local server), the name does not display. All I see is **Hi!**.
Wanted to know if I was entering anything wrong or had improper syntax? I am new to PHP!

I am using 'woocommecre' and `wordpress` and my code is below:

Thank you!

**customer-new-account.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer new account email
 *
 * @author         WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $woocommerce;

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );


?>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading); ?>


<table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
       <td valign="top" style="padding-bottom: 0;">
         <div style="color: #6D6E71; font-size:14px; line-height:150%; padding:0;">
             <h2 style="color: #231F20;"><?php printf( __( 'Hi', 'woocommerce' ), $order->billing_first_name); ?>!</h2>**
             </h2>
          </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

**Edit**

Here are the results when I use `<pre><?php print_r($order) ?></pre>` to debug.

```
WC_Order Object
(
    [id] => 
    [prices_include_tax] => 
    [tax_display_cart] => excl
    [display_totals_ex_tax] => 1
    [display_cart_ex_tax] => 1
)
```

Comment: what does the output of `print_r($order)` look like?

Comment: I see! I am not to sure how to view errors in woocommerce or PHP in general, where would I add that line? or even go about looking for the result it gives?

Comment: Write this `<pre><?php print_r($order) ?> </pre>` online line above your <h2> tag.  It's not an error, it will just print out the values of the $order array.  And edit your question to include the result (if it's not insanely long)

Comment: @Dan just added the results to the section!

Comment: Ok, so your problem is that `billing_first_name` is not in the array that you're retrieving. Look at woocommerce documentation and double check to find out where that information is.  You may have to make another API call.

Comment: Does this not work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819054/get-customers-name-in-woocommerce