# Customer Details

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

woocommerce question related to a Customer. A similar post is here although the data within the $order object is not available for me?

[Get customers name in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819054/get-customers-name-in-woocommerce)

Problem: I need to get the customers details (any customer - logged in or one-time) in real time on purchase and on admin order status changes.

E.g. Not logged in customer purchases a product. Once the product status is 'completed' I catch this action and do something within the function

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'woocommerce_payment_completed' );
```

At this point I can retrieve the Order ID and most things related to the Order. The customer details elude me though...

If the customer was logged in I can use $user_id but if they do not have an account on the site then where can I get their name/email etc?

Trying a few things... Here is the output of

```
$order->get_user(), new WC_Customer(), $order itself.
```

Results:

```html
boolean false
object(WC_Customer)[106]
  protected '_data' => 
    array (size=14)
      'country' => string 'AU' (length=2)
      'state' => string '' (length=0)
      'postcode' => string '' (length=0)
      'city' => string '' (length=0)
      'address' => string '' (length=0)
      'address_2' => string '' (length=0)
      'shipping_country' => string 'AU' (length=2)
      'shipping_state' => string '' (length=0)
      'shipping_postcode' => string '' (length=0)
      'shipping_city' => string '' (length=0)
      'shipping_address' => string '' (length=0)
      'shipping_address_2' => string '' (length=0)
      'is_vat_exempt' => boolean false
      'calculated_shipping' => boolean false
  private '_changed' => boolean false
object(WC_Order)[134]
  public 'id' => int 44
  public 'order_type' => string 'simple' (length=6)
  public 'prices_include_tax' => boolean true
  public 'tax_display_cart' => string 'incl' (length=4)
  public 'display_totals_ex_tax' => boolean false
  public 'display_cart_ex_tax' => boolean false
  public 'post' => 
    object(WP_Post)[132]
      public 'ID' => int 44
      public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'post_date' => string '2014-11-25 05:07:55' (length=19)
      public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2014-11-25 05:07:55' (length=19)
      public 'post_content' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_title' => string 'Order &ndash; November 25, 2014 @ 05:07 AM' (length=42)
      public 'post_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_status' => string 'wc-on-hold' (length=10)
      public 'comment_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'ping_status' => string 'closed' (length=6)
      public 'post_password' => string 'order_54740eab99424' (length=19)
      public 'post_name' => string 'order-nov-25-2014-0507-am' (length=25)
      public 'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_modified' => string '2014-11-25 05:07:55' (length=19)
      public 'post_modified_gmt' => string '2014-11-25 05:07:55' (length=19)
      public 'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_parent' => int 0
      public 'guid' => string 'http://essential.localtest.me/?post_type=shop_order&#038;p=44' (length=61)
      public 'menu_order' => int 0
      public 'post_type' => string 'shop_order' (length=10)
      public 'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'comment_count' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
  public 'order_date' => string '2014-11-25 05:07:55' (length=19)
  public 'modified_date' => string '2014-11-25 05:07:55' (length=19)
  public 'customer_message' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'customer_note' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_status' => string 'wc-on-hold' (length=10)
  public 'shipping_address' => string 'anothe address, Sydney, NSW, 2011, AU' (length=37)
  public 'billing_address' => string 'anothe address, Sydney, NSW, 2011, AU' (length=37)
```

EDIT: !!!!
So, it seems my knowledge of Wordpress is still beginner.
What seems to be happening is that the data is stored in wp_postmeta table. This data is accessible (somehow) and the fields (or meta_key) I'm looking for are _billing_first_name, _billing_last_name which is accessible via $order->billing_last_name; etc... (Assuming $order is WC_Order() object with valid order ID)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819054/get-customers-name-in-woocommerce ... Sorry, it seems that the abstract class probably has some variables which I couldn't see.... This is probably the where I should continue although for the life of me I cannot see billing_email as a member variable anywhere???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woocommerce classes have magic getters and setters. It's mean that you can't see the data with a var_dump because it's dynamically get from database on demand.

There is an exemple the magic function for the order object:
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L805

As you can see, when you ask an unknown meta data it goes directly to database.

ex. if you write : `$order->billing_last_name` you will produce : `get_post_meta( $this->id, '_billing_last_name', true );`

So, if you want to see all the meta data of an order (works on products / coupon / etc) you have to directly ask the database in order to see which data is available and then you can use it properly on your code.

Hope it's helps

Comment: Thanks for the proper definition and answer @XciD.